# Java TreeMap alternative

Tags: java, data-structures

I am in need of a data structure that has fast insert, fast retrieve, and can be returned in order. This sounds like a tree map but I need the order of the elements to be based on a creation time NOT on the order of the keys I am storing.

In other words, I still want to be able to insert and retrieve based on a key (which is a string) but I want to get the items back in order of creation time (which is a date). Of course I want this to be as fast as possible and not to have to create my own data type.

The tree map will not work in this case because it uses the key for insert and retrieve AND for ordering the results. Is there another standard data type that would satisfy my requirements?

Comment: Why don't you implement the `compareTo` method by implementing `Comparable` so as to consider the dates and then use the regular `TreeMap` implementation?

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding your comment but the constructor for the tree map takes a Comparable that has the type of the key NOT the value (my creation time is in the value object)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you want a [LinkedHashMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html).

Answer (score 1):

use a Map and a TreeSet?

One Map<String,Object> just to store the key/value pairs. It doesn't have to be a TreeMap. Because you're not using that map for its sorting.

The TreeSet<Object> is use for its sorting.

You can always wrap 2 collection instances in one wrapper Map class that you create yourself. If you really need it to look like one map. Make sure your chosen Comparator uses the creation date.

The other guys are suggesting a LinkedHashMap. But I don't think you want to maintain "insert order". But instead you want it sorting by a comparator of some type (maybe Object.equals).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can create your own `Comparator` and use `public TreeMap(Comparator<? super K> comparator)` constructor.

Comment: The constructor accepts a comparator with the type of the key only. The creation time is part of the value object not the key so it won't work.